# What would be the most general effective Lagrangian involving one Higgs and two gluons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model

Two different possibilities come into my mind

$\mathcal{L}\sim{}HG_{\mu}G^{\mu}$

where $G^{\mu}$ is the gluon field and $H$ the Higgs, or either

$\mathcal{L}\sim{}HG_{\mu\nu}G^{\mu\nu}$

Where $G_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}G_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}G_{\mu}$.

I can't think of any argument to decide, so, which of this is best and why? or is there a better choice?

Comment: What do you mean, *"two gluons"*? The number of gluons is the dimension of the gauge group, not determined by the term in the Lagrangian. Why does $G$ have only one index in your first possibility, but two in the second?

Comment: @ACuriousMind with two gluons I mean that I want an interaction term giving a vertex with two gluons and a Higgs. The second G has two indices because it is the field strength (i will edit that)

Comment: Neither of these is gauge invariant - you'll have to have a trace over the group index (like $G^a_{\mu\nu} G^{\mu\nu a}$), and for the first, I see no easy fix.

Comment: @ACuriousMind maybe this is a stupid question, but couldn't we relax the gauge invariance condition in an effective theory?

Comment: And how would saying "this is an effective theory" change the fact that gauge invariance of the theory is required? (I'm not saying it's not possible, I just don't see how that would come about)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't know. I just wonder if it is possible or not.

Comment: @silvrfück: You want your effective theory to respect the symmetries of your theory. Since we don't think QCD is spontaneously broken by the new dynamics at the EW scale, we want the electroweak operators to respect SU(3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, since we are talking about an effective theory, there are infinitely many terms. Since the theory does not have to be renormalizable, we can include all operators with $D>4$. So I think you want the easiest one, namely only one additional operator giving you the $Hgg$-vertex.

This would, as you say correctly, be something like

$\delta \mathcal{L}\sim \frac{g}{\Lambda}H G_{\mu\nu}^a G^{\mu\nu\ a} + h.c.$

BTW: $G_{\mu\nu}^a=\partial_\mu A_\nu^a - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a+ g_s f^{abc}A_\mu^b A_\nu^c$. Gluons interact with each other.

Within the Standard Model, such an interaction could be realized through a, say, top-quark loop. In an effective theory, you would then let $m_{top}\rightarrow \infty$ to get the effective vertex. This can be done, when $m_{top}\gg \mu$, where $\mu$ is the mass of some other particle. Now in our case $\frac{m_{Higgs}}{m_{top}}\approx 0.72$. Though, it is $<1$, I don't know if $m_{top}\gg m_{Higgs}$ is an assumtion you can make.